# Object embedded in Databricks SQL command

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql

I came across the following SQL command in Databricks notebook and I am confused about what is this **${da.paths.working_dir}** object in following SQL command. Is it a python object or something else?

SELECT * FROM parquet.`${da.paths.working_dir}/weather`

I know it contains the path of a working directory but how can I access/print it.
I tried to demystify it but failed as illustrated in the following figure.
[image]

**NOTE**: My notebook is SQL notebook

Comment: Is your code example written in Scala?

Comment: @AlexOtt, No, the code is in SQL. This is SQL notebook.

Comment: I even check the same code using Scala magic command but still got an error.  In a later video, Instructor mentioned at one place, that this is a high-level variable. But still, I am confused this is a high-level variable in what (Python, SQL, Scala, bash)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out. This is a high-level variable in Databricks SQL and we can access it using the **SELECT** keyword in Databricks SQL as shown below:

```
SELECT '${da.paths.working_dir}';
```

[image]

**EDIT:** This high variable is spark configuration which can be set as follows:

```
## spark.conf.set(key, value)
spark.conf.set(da.paths.working_dir, "/path/to/files")
```

To access this property in **python:**

```
spark.conf.get(da.paths.working_dir)
```

To access this property in **Databricks SQL:**

SELECT `{da.paths.working_dir}`

Comment: Thanks for sharing the details of your discovery